# Neo4j Generate nodes with unique ID importing a CSV

Tags: neo4j

I have 2 types of nodes in differents csv files I want that every node has a unique ID.

I'm trying this:

```
MERGE (id:GlobalUniqueId)
ON CREATE SET id.count = 1
ON MATCH SET id.count = id.count + 1
WITH id.count AS uid
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/csv/user.csv' AS line  
    CREATE (:User {Id: uid, IdUser: line.idUser, ScreenName: line.screenName});

MERGE (id:GlobalUniqueId)
ON CREATE SET id.count = 1
ON MATCH SET id.count = id.count + 1
WITH id.count AS uid
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/csv/language.csv' AS line  
    MERGE (:Language {Id: uid, IsoLanguageCode: line.isoLanguageCode});
```

But this generates the same ID for all User nodes and the same identifier incremented by one for all Languages nodes.
I want that every node has a different identifier any idea?

Comment: The reason you're getting the same id for each node; Your code isn't doing a `MERGE` per CSV line; it's doing it *once*. You're then taking that id, alias it as `uid`, and assigning that same value to every single node in your `LOAD CSV` operation.

Comment: There's anyway to do the merge per csv line?

Comment: @user2238244 If you need a unique identifier without any additional restrictions, you can generate uuid with `apoс`: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures#creating-data